# How to avoid duplicate values in a LOV on a adf input table

Tags: oracle-adf, lov

I have a input table with a LOV field. Values in the LOV are coming from a VO which is join based VO. So key attributes are from all the Eos which are joined. My LOV is defined over one of the key attribute of a EO. So i am getting duplicate values in the LOV due to joins. What can be fix for this ?

Comment: Please elaborate with example or put your query for easy understanding

Comment: Sounds like a query thing not an ADF thing. You need to test the query outside of ADF and make sure it does not return duplicates. if it does, fix the query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try introducing the "Distinct" into your query?
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php